# Calculate tax liabilities based on a marginal tax rate schedule

Tags: python, pandas, tax, bisect

[income tax calculation python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20130478/1840471) asks how to calculate taxes given a marginal tax rate schedule, and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130489/1840471) provides a function that works (below).

However, it works only for a single value of income. How would I adapt it to work for a list/numpy array/pandas Series of income values? That is, how do I vectorize this code?

```
from bisect import bisect

rates = [0, 10, 20, 30]   # 10%  20%  30%

brackets = [10000,        # first 10,000
            30000,        # next  20,000
            70000]        # next  40,000

base_tax = [0,            # 10,000 * 0%
            2000,         # 20,000 * 10%
            10000]        # 40,000 * 20% + 2,000

def tax(income):
    i = bisect(brackets, income)
    if not i:
        return 0
    rate = rates[i]
    bracket = brackets[i-1]
    income_in_bracket = income - bracket
    tax_in_bracket = income_in_bracket * rate / 100
    total_tax = base_tax[i-1] + tax_in_bracket
    return total_tax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method implements the vectorized marginal tax calculations just using NumPy if it's needed.

```
def tax(incomes, bands, rates):
    # Broadcast incomes so that we can compute an amount per income, per band
    incomes_ = np.broadcast_to(incomes, (bands.shape[0] - 1, incomes.shape[0]))
    # Find amounts in bands for each income
    amounts_in_bands = np.clip(incomes_.transpose(),
                               bands[:-1], bands[1:]) - bands[:-1]
    # Calculate tax per band
    taxes = rates * amounts_in_bands
    # Sum tax bands per income
    return taxes.sum(axis=1)
```

For usage, bands should include the upper limit - in my view this makes it more explicit.

```
incomes = np.array([0, 7000, 14000, 28000, 56000, 77000, 210000])
bands = np.array([0, 12500, 50000, 150000, np.inf])
rates = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.45])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['pre_tax'] = incomes
df['post_tax'] = incomes - tax(incomes, bands, rates)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   pre_tax  post_tax
0        0       0.0
1     7000    7000.0
2    14000   13700.0
3    28000   24900.0
4    56000   46100.0
5    77000   58700.0
6   210000  135500.0
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to avoid `pandas`. Would this give `NaN`s if income is provided in excess of the upper limit? Could you do a time test on some large data (e.g. with `%%timeit` in Jupyter)? Happy to accept this if it's faster, though if `np.inf` is always the implied rightmost value I'd favor dropping it as in the question.

Comment: Thanks - here's a [notebook](https://github.com/nikhilwoodruff/marginal-tax/blob/master/tax.ipynb) with some speed testing: I get slightly (8%) faster results. The infinity was trivial to add, just appended it onto the bands and NaNs shouldn't make an appearance (even if the top band explicitly isn't infinity) - as it just calculates the amount in each band.

Comment: Thanks for doing the speed test. Since it's faster, more concise, and uses fewer dependencies, I changed this to the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. It's easy to read, which is worth a lot.   However, in order to make this truly practical, what's really needed is a function that will spit out the tax for *any* income amount on a sliding scale, given two different brackets, one for federal tax brackets and one for  state (or provincial) tax brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Two data frames are created, one for the tax parameters and one for the incomes.
For each income, we get the corresponding row indexes from the tax table, using the "searchsorted" method.
With that index we create a new table (df_tax.loc[rows]) and concatenate it with the income table,
then calculate the taxes, and drop the unnecessary columns.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

    # Test data:
    df=pd.DataFrame({"name":["Bob","Julie","Mary","John","Bill","George","Andie"], \
                    "income":[0, 9_000, 10_000, 11_000, 30_000, 69_999, 200_000]})   
    OUT:
         name  income
    0     Bob       0
    1   Julie    9000
    2    Mary   10000
    3    John   11000
    4    Bill   30000
    5  George   69999
    6   Andie  200000

df_tax=pd.DataFrame({"brackets": [0, 10_000, 30_000, 70_000 ],   # lower limits
                     "rates":    [0,  .10,    .20,    .30   ],
                     "base_tax": [0,   0,    2_000,  10_000 ]} )


rows= df_tax["brackets"].searchsorted(df["income"], side="right") - 1  # aka bisect()
OUT:
[0 0 1 1 2 2 3]

df= pd.concat([df,df_tax.loc[rows].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) 

df["total_tax"]= df["income"].sub(df["brackets"]).mul(df["rates"]).add(df["base_tax"])

OUT:
     name  income  brackets  rates  base_tax  total_tax
0     Bob       0         0    0.0         0        0.0
1   Julie    9000         0    0.0         0        0.0
2    Mary   10000     10000    0.1         0        0.0
3    John   11000     10000    0.1         0      100.0
4    Bill   30000     30000    0.2      2000     2000.0
5  George   69999     30000    0.2      2000     9999.8
6   Andie  200000     70000    0.3     10000    49000.0

df=df.reindex(columns=["name","income","total_tax"])
OUT:
     name  income  total_tax
0     Bob       0        0.0
1   Julie    9000        0.0
2    Mary   10000        0.0
3    John   11000      100.0
4    Bill   30000     2000.0
5  George   69999     9999.8
6   Andie  200000    49000.0
```

**Edit:**

At the beginning, you can calculate the base_tax, too:

```
df_tax["base_tax"]= df_tax.brackets   #edit2
                .sub(df_tax.brackets.shift(fill_value=0))
                .mul(df_tax.rates.shift(fill_value=0))
                .cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks, though the edit base_tax calculation produces NaNs for rows 4-6

Comment: Sorry. It must be df_tax["base_tax"] and not df["base_tax"]. Corrected. You can apply it at the beginning when set up the df_tax table, so you must specify only the brackets and rates explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One (probably inefficient) way is to use list comprehension:

```
def tax_multiple(incomes):
    return [tax(income) for income in incomes]
```

Comment: Where do you see possibe improvements in performance? Either way, you have to do the calculations for each income.

Comment: In general, vectorization is often much faster than list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting kantal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58150172/1840471) to run as a function:

```
def income_tax(income, brackets, rates):
    df_tax = pd.DataFrame({'brackets': brackets, 'rates': rates})
    df_tax['base_tax'] = df_tax.brackets.\
        sub(df_tax.brackets.shift(fill_value=0)).\
        mul(df_tax.rates.shift(fill_value=0)).cumsum()
    rows = df_tax.brackets.searchsorted(income, side='right') - 1
    income_bracket_df = df_tax.loc[rows].reset_index(drop=True)
    return pd.Series(income).sub(income_bracket_df.brackets).\
        mul(income_bracket_df.rates).add(income_bracket_df.base_tax)
```

e.g.:

```
income = [0, 9_000, 10_000, 11_000, 30_000, 69_999, 200_000]
brackets = [0, 10_000, 30_000, 70_000]  # Lower limits.
rates =    [0,    .10,    .20,    .30]

income_tax(income, brackets, rates).tolist()
# [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 2000.0, 9999.8, 49000.0]
```